# How to format MM/YY placeholder as the user types? 2M/YY -> 20/2Y -> 20/22

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, bootstrap-4

I want to format the placeholder in such a way that user can enter date and like 2M/YY and then 20/YY till its 20/2Y - 20/22. The place holder should go when the user types.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @NinaScholz Jeet wants to still see the placeholder until they finished typing a correct format